# How to Post object array to php

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, arrays, web-services

I am working on an asp.net application. I need to call php webservice.I am using Asp.net web Reference to connect the webservice. I need to pass a object array. But WebReference class not correctly converting it to xml format so php cant find data what I send.

Below shows my code:

**C# class**

```
 public class item{
    public string id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set}
 }
```

The webReference should convert it into below format

**xml**

```
<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>2</name>
</item>
```

I am trying a lot of methods but nothing works.

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question, so it will be *easier* for people to suggest a (more accurate / better) solution.

Comment: You should modify your PHP script to accept a JSON response, so it can do json_decode on it. hen in C#, you can easily convert for item to json using JavaScriptSerializerClass